# 0 ETH Airdrop function with ICO contract

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, tokens, ico

I see many airdrops that have been done by sending 0 ETH to the ICO contract address

my question is: how to add this function to the ICO contract with the ability to start and stop at any time?
and if there an ready contract with ICO functions and the function that I mentioned above, please insert it

Comment: to implement start/stop look at OpenZeppelin crowdsale contract, the interface is called `Pausable`

Comment: did you have a contract with the mentioned function ?